# PolylineOptions's weight() attribute doesn't seem to work

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to draw a Polyline on my GoogleMap object with custom width, which you're meant to set in PolylineOptions according to the docs. That's all fine and dandy, except it doesn't actually set the weight. Seems to be keeping the default 10px with no matter what I set it as. Any pointers?

```
PolylineOptions opts = new PolylineOptions();
opts.add(point);
opts.add(otherpoint);
opts.color(whatevercolor);
opts.width(justAboutAnyNumberYouCouldImagineAndItDoesntEvenMatter);
Polyline pl = map.addPolyline(opts);
```

To be clear; the line DOES get drawn with the specified parameters, all except the weight... help?

Answer (score 0):

Fab,  I'm not seeing strokeWeight in your example.  This example works and sets the strokeWeight to a ridiculous width.

```
var scale = new google.maps.Polyline()
scale.setPath( [scaleStart, horizontalLineStart, horizontalLineEnd,  scaleEnd])
scale.setOptions({strokeWeight:50, visible:true})
scale.setMap(map)
```

Comment: This is for the Android API, not web - but all the same yeah my mistake was to have mistaken "width" for "weight" and never clued into it